# openapi-code-generator 3.3.4 does not read the tags and API class name is not expected

Tags: java, java-8, openapi-generator

I have below `openapi` document. I expected the API class name to be generated will be `SampleApi` because the operation "/hello" is tagged with "sample" 
`tags`. But it is generating the API class name using the `operation` name, it is `HelloApi`. What am I missing here? I am using `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` version `3.3.1`

`openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Sample Service
tags:
  - name: sample
paths:
  /hello:
    get:
      summary: Says hello world
      operationId: greet
      tags:
        - sample
      responses:
        200:
          description: ok
          content:
            plain/text:

              schema:
                type: string
                example: Hello World`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found solution. We need to use option `useTags` set to `true` in the `configOptions` section of the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`

By default `useTags` set to `false` so it will not use the tag name to create the API class name.

```
<configOptions>
  <sourceFolder>openapi</sourceFolder>
  <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
  <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
  <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
  <useTags>true</useTags>
</configOptions>
```

Comment: I have two paths, doing the same as you, but api interface generated is named DefaultApi, do you know what is the reason?